# What rap subgenre is T.I. "Do Ya Thang"

Tags: genre, rap, hip-hop

[T.I. - Do Ya Thang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h1CV-jqdto) - what genre is it? Google says it's a hip-hop/rap, but what kind of rap specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T.I.'s music is generally characterized as "trap music," an increasingly popular subgenre of rap that he popularized on his album *Trap Muzik.*

> Trap is a style of southern rap tunes that was developed in the late 1990s to early 2000s in the Southern United States. It is typified by sub-divided hi-hats, heavy, sub-bass layered kick drums in the style of the Roland TR-808 drum machine, typically in half time syncopated rhythms, layered with drones expressed by muted or slightly muted abstract or orchestral synthesizers and an overall melancholy to dark ambience and lyrical content.The term "trap" referred to places where drug deals take place. In the 2010s, artists crossbred trap with dubstep to create trap EDM.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music